# tensorflow error: module has no attribute GraphDef

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am following this tutorial [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) and I am running into an error 20 minutes after I run the code. Here is the code and the error.

the code is here [code](https://pythonprogramming.net/video-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/)

error:

```
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'
```

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your code directly in the question body

Answer (score 0):

You may be using tensorflow 2.0. If that is the case, to use TF-1 within TF-2, the import statement should be edited as below.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior( )
```

Answer (score 0):

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'/ 'Session'**

Since the version of tf2 is under Ubuntu, it will be different from the previous version.

change `tf.GraphDef()` -> `tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()`

change `tf.Session()` -> `tf.compat.v1.Session()`